# PHP merge array

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => wahyu@email.co.id
    [1] => wahyu@email.co.id
)
Array
(
    [0] => wahyu@email.co.id
    [1] => wahyu@email.co.id
)
```

I would like to combine array above like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => wahyu@email.co.id
    [1] => wahyu@email.co.id
    [2] => wahyu@email.co.id
    [3] => wahyu@email.co.id
)
```

How the way to combine it?

Comment: What's the problem?  `$c=array_merge($a,$b);`

Comment: the problem, I use foreach, this my code:
foreach($model->data as $value){
 $emailuser = $this->mail($value->email->user);
}

Comment: @RahulMeshram What a problem are you expecting with array_merge? - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bdc73bfc0fb311bcc74d35de2923079e7fe3cfcf

Answer (score 2):

**array_merge** function is used for the combine two array.

```
$a = array("0" => "one@email.co.id",
    "1" => "two@email.co.id"
);

$b = array(
    "0" => "three@email.co.id",
    "1" => "four@email.co.id"
);


$merged_array = array_merge($a,$b);

echo "<prE>";
print_r($merged_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

use array_merge(arr_1,arr_2,arr_3) function to merge two or more arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_merge` to combine both arrays like this:

```
$arr1 = ['wahyu@email.co.id', 'wahyu@email.co.id'];
$arr2 = ['wahyu@email.co.id', 'wahyu@email.co.id'];
$arr3 = array_merge($arr1, arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

=> Try `array_merge()` Function to merge two array.

```
<?php
$a1=array("wahyu@email.co.id","wahyu@email.co.id");
$a2=array("wahyu@email.co.id","wahyu@email.co.id");
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
?>
```

Demo:-
https://paiza.io/projects/5-7Cdo5GIMenayUP0cIDGg

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve like this way.

PHP has built-in function `array_merge`.

For example:

```
$newArray = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP `array_merge`...

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values
>   of one are appended to the end of the previous one.

see docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
<?php
$array1 = array("email@domain.com","email2@domain.com");
$array2 = array("email3@domain.com","email4@domain.com");

$array_merged = array_merge($array1, $array2);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for,

```
$array1 = [
    0 => 'wahyu@email.co.id',
    1 => 'wahyu@email.co.id',
];
$array2 = [
    0 => 'wahyu@email.co.id',
    1 => 'wahyu@email.co.id',
];
array_splice($array1, count($array1), 0, $array2);
print_r($array1);
```

[array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) — Remove a portion of the array and replace it with something else

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => wahyu@email.co.id
    [1] => wahyu@email.co.id
    [2] => wahyu@email.co.id
    [3] => wahyu@email.co.id
)
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/01c8c073400813735b450183588ef82200808988).